# Motors don't move when printing but do when homing

Tags: marlin, motor, print-failure, homing, mks

I have an MKS Robin Pro I was starting a print on and the motors were not moving. The progress bar was running and the extruder temperature was changing (IDEX printer) so I thought it was printing but the motors were not moving, so nothing actually happened. When I home the printer, however, the motors do turn and go to the home position in fact.

Does anyone know how to fix this?